# Nuxt 3 server does not stop when restarting supervisor job

Tags: node.js, supervisord, nuxtjs3

I have set up a production environment for a nuxt app where the nuxt server gets run through a supervisor job. When the port is not in use this works well. However, if I issue the `supervisorctl reload` or `supervisorctl restart production-frontend` commands the previous nuxt server usually fails to exit. This means that when it tries to start the nuxt server again it errors out.

Is there a special trick to get nuxt to work nicely with supervisor or a parameter I can add to the supervisor process so the nuxt server guaranteed shuts down when I restart it? I would rather not have to resort to giving the deploy process the power to kill any previous process that still may be lingering through `kill -9` like I now have to do manually.

This is the content of `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/production-frontend.conf`

```
[program:production-frontend]
command=/usr/bin/npm start
directory=/var/www/production/frontend
environment=NODE_ENV="production",PORT="3011"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
startsecs=30
user=www-data
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/production-frontend_error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/production-frontend_out.log
```

`/var/www/production/frontend` contains the `.output` folder from a `npm run build` command and a `package.json` file. `npm run start` will start the nuxt server with `node .output/server/index.mjs`.

Whenever the server fails to start the error log shows the following error message:

```
[nitro] [dev] [uncaughtException] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3011
```

Running `netstat -pln | grep 3011` shows a still running nuxt server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out `npm start` will run a command

```
sh -c -- node .output/server/index.mjs
```

This in turn will start a process

```
node .output/server/index.mjs
```

This can be verified with in a shell with the following commands. Note that 191667 is the parent (sh) and 191668 is the nuxt server.

```
$ netstat -pln | grep 3301
tcp6       0      0 :::3011                 :::*                    LISTEN      191668/node
$ pstree -p 191668
sh(191667)───node(191668)─┬─{node}(191669)
                          ├─{node}(191670)
                          ├─{node}(191671)
                          ├─{node}(191672)
                          ├─{node}(191673)
                          ├─{node}(191674)
                          ├─{node}(191675)
                          ├─{node}(191676)
                          ├─{node}(191677)
                          └─{node}(191678)
```

Supervisor will kill the parent process, but not the child process. Instead just run the command directly. In my case running `node .output/server.index.mjs` is fine. If something is not installed globally you might need to define the entire path to whatever you are trying to run (e.g. `./node_modules/jest/bin/jest this_makes_no_sense_for_supervisor`.